# New error but no code changes! - TypeError: '<=' not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, pdfminer

I am an inexperienced developer cobbling things together but no deep knowledge and I have come unstuck!

I have a Google Cloud Function running some code that uses pdfmier.six to extract content from a PDF and that has been working well. However I tried it today (not used it for approx 2 weeks) and found it was erroring with the following error:

`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

The error occurs on both a live GCF and on local machine using Functions Framework.

I tried a two main things to diagnose the issue:

- roll back to previous version of the code -> still same error
- ran locally out of the Functions Framework -> worked fine

If I am interpreting this correctly then it appears that something has changed in the way the GCF works but now lost how to deal with this.

Here is the error in full:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 98, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "/Users/philwakefield/Documents/OpenSet/openset_proj/src/pdf extract/main.py", line 100, in PdfExtract
    interpreter.process_page(page)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 842, in process_page
    self.device.end_page(page)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdfminer/converter.py", line 48, in end_page
    self.cur_item.analyze(self.laparams)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdfminer/layout.py", line 679, in analyze
    if -1 <= laparams.boxes_flow and laparams.boxes_flow <= +1 and textboxes:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is an extract of the code up to the error point:

```
#extract the data
with urllib.request.urlopen(pdf_path) as url:
    fp = open('openset_schedule_1.pdf', 'rb')
    #fp = io.BytesIO(url.read())

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams(boxes_flow=None, line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    interpreter.process_page(page)
```

Comment: Fir whatever reason `laparams.boxes_flow` is `None`. That's all we can say without more info

Comment: Thanks @buran - fair. I guess my question is more why this would be the case when running as a GCF but not when running outside of the functions framework. All other inputs and code are the same. Are there any particular things I can provide that would help diagnose?

Comment: `laparams = LAParams(boxes_flow=None, line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)` would appear to set `laparams.boxes_flow` to `None`. The traceback suggests that the error is coming from the `interpreter =` line, which means that the `device = `line should have updated that `None` to something else and hasn't. Without knowing what `PDFPageAggregator` is, it's not possible to say any more. Has a library been updated when it should have been pinned, maybe?

Comment: Fixed - changed laparams = 'LAParams(boxes_flow=None, line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)' to 'laparams = LAParams(line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)'. 'boxes_flow=None' was being interpreted differently (will track down why!) but removing this optional parameter has fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
laparams = LAParams(boxes_flow=None, line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)
```

to

```
laparams = LAParams(line_margin=0.2, char_margin=0.5)
```

The `boxes_flow=None` was being interpreted differently (will track down why), but removing this optional parameter has fixed it.